# Why or how does this prove JavaScript array equality?

Tags: javascript, arrays, equality

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8618383/7329) there is a simple function that will return array equality for arrays that contain primitive values.

However, I'm not sure why it works.  Here is the function:

```
function arrays_equal(a,b) { return !!a && !!b && !(a<b || b<a); }
```

I'm mostly interested in the second half; this bit:

```
!(a<b || b<a)
```

Why does the `<` and `>` work when comparing the arrays but the `==` doesn't?

How do the less than and greater than methods work within JavaScript?

Answer (score 11):

With `<`/`>`, the arrays are converted to strings first, and as such do not provide a reliable method of checking equality.

`==` does not work because objects are checked by reference:

```
[] == []; // false, two separate objects

var a = [];
a == a; // true, refer to the same object
```

The `<`/`>` trick is flawed:

```
var a = [1, [2, 3]],
    b = [[1, 2], 3];

!(a<b || b<a); // true
```

This evaluates to `true`, because they are both converted to the string `"1,2,3"` before they are checked (`<`/`>` do not "directly" work for objects).

So basically, you are comparing equality of the strings. For strings, `a == b` is indeed the same as `!(a<b || b<a)` - `<`/`>` for strings check character codes, so two equal strings are neither "smaller" nor "greater" because that's not the case for any character code in the strings.

Comment: @Sarfraz: Yes, until you discover things like this yourself after some nasty debugging...

Comment: Have recently started learning it **seriously**, going forward :). You should have a blog by the way :)

Comment: A more reliable alternative might be `JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b)`.

Comment: @gilly: True, unless the arrays [contain objects themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191791/javascript-compare-arrays-of-objects-optimal-way/9191823#comment11566854_9191823).

Comment: @gilly3: There'll be other issues as well. `JSON.stringify([function(){}]) == JSON.stringify([,]) // true`.

Comment: @pimvdb so, does it (1,2,3) means "49, 50, 51" or 49, 50, 51 or anything else ?

Comment: @Heera: I'm sorry, what are those numbers (`49`) referring to?

Comment: As you said for strings check character codes and is that mean (1=49, 2=50, 3=51), i.e  [1,2,3]>[1,2,3] means 49, 50, 51 > 49, 50, 51 ? I meant, is this the way the javascript interpreter sees these, please, I'm confused.

Comment: @Heera: Ah I missed that - I don't know those codes off the top of my head :) Yes, you're correct, but note that the commas are also in the string. Anyway, consider a more trivial example: `"1" > "2"` is false because `49 > 50` is false. Likewise, the opposite is true.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very so much, it was a grate help, my image on my mind is now so clear. Thanks again!

Comment: thank you, each of the distinct answers so far have each taught me something;  I appreciate you taking the time to answer!

Comment: The point of most of these arguments is basically that you can't use something simple like this as a generic utility function.  But, from a more practical standpoint, if your arrays are in a known format (eg, comparing two simple string arrays), a function like this is certainly adequate.

Comment: @gilly3: Most certainly; I just think it's a good idea to know of its "quirks" if you are using someone else's function.

Comment: As this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/a/3198202/913845) suggests you should just use Underscore.js isEqual: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isEqual Underscore.js has tons of other useful stuff so it is well worth including in your page if you are doing any serious JavaScript on it.

Answer (score 5):

> However, I'm not sure why it works.

It doesn't work.  Consider

```
arrays_equal(["1,2"], [1,2])
```

produces true even though by any definition of array equality based on element-wise comparison, they are different.

```
arrays_equal([[]], [])
```

and

```
arrays_equal([""], [])
```

are also spurious positives.

Simply adding `length` checking won't help as demonstrated by

```
arrays_equal(["1,2",3], [1,"2,3"])

arrays_equal(
    ["",","],
    [",",""])
```

EDIT:

If you want a succinct way to test structural similarity, I suggest:

```
function structurallyEquivalent(a, b) {
  return JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b);
}
```

It doesn't stop early on inputs that are obviously different -- it walks both object graphs regardless of how disimilar they are, but so does the function in the OP.

One caveat: when you're using non-native `JSON.stringify`, it may do strange things for cyclic inputs like:

```
var input = [];
input[0] = input;
```

Comment: Even for primitives, `JSON.stringify` might not be fully reliable. Consider `[,]` and `[null]`.

Comment: @pimvdb, Sure.  It conflates `null` and `undefined`/elipsis but so does JavaScript `==`.  Nothing in the OP expresses a preference for `===` over `==`.

Comment: Thanks, your answer further aided in my understanding along with @pimvdb's.

Answer (score 4):

You can compare any two objects using `==`. But since > and < are not defined for objects, they are converted to strings. Therefore, `[1,2,3]>[2,1,3]` is actually doing `"1,2,3">"2,1,3"`

Comment: this is not correct.  Conversion is not always to string.  [11.8.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.8.5) specifies that object conversion happens with type hint `"number"` so `arrays_equal(new Date(1), 1)` is `true`.

Comment: Thanks; and to Mike for the clarification in his comment!